# Keep in-memory data structures of two processes in sync

Tags: algorithm, visual-c++, high-availability, in-memory, vsync

How do I keep the in-memory data structures in sync between two processes. Both processes are the same process(server) - one is active and the other one is a stand-by. The stand-by needs to take over in case of crash/or similar of the active. For the standby to take over the active, the in-memory data structures need to be kept in-sync. Can I use Virtual Synchrony? Will it help? If it would is there any library that I can use? I am coding on C++ on Windows(Visual Studio).

If that is not a solution what is a good solution I can refer to?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution to implement is to store the state in a separate database, so that when you fail over, the standby will just continue using the same database. If you are worried about the database crashing, pay the money and complexity required to have main and standby databases, with the database also failing over. This is an attempt to push the complexity of handling state across failovers onto the database. Of course you may find that the overhead of database transactions becomes a bottleneck. It might be tempting to go NoSQL for this, but remember that you are probably relying on the ACID guarantees you get with a traditional database. If you ditch these, typically getting eventual consistency in return, you will have to think about what this means on failover. Will you lose a small amount of recent information on failover? do you care?

Virtual synchrony looks interesting. I have searched for similar things and found academic pages like http://www.cs.cornell.edu/ken/, some of which, like this, have links to open source software produced by research groups. I have never used them. I seem to remember reports that they worked pretty well for small number of machines with very good connectivity, but hit performance problems with scale, which I presume won't be a problem for you.

Once upon a time people built multiprocess systems on Unix machines by having the processes communicate via shared memory, or memory mapped files. For very simple data structures, this can be made to work. One problem you have is if one of the processes crashes halfway through modifying the shared data - will this mess up the other processes? You can solve these problems, but you are in danger of discovering that you have implemented everything inside the database that I described in my first paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for in memory database like memcached or redis.

Comment: Wow, thanks for that! I saw your reply yesterday and I researched on redis. I would like to use this with huge code. We have maybe like 500 classes and other data structures. So would I need to add to the constructor of those classes to get the information from redis and in the destructor/other setter functions to commit the change into redis?